# How to pull an article from the XML feed of a news site?

Tags: android, xml, wordpress, rest

I have a concept to build a native Android app for a WordPress website.  The feed is in XML and it has everything that I need except the tag that houses the article itself.  I understand why this may be the case but I still want to display the article itself in the app as well alongside whatever header image it came with.

I usually only parsed with JSON so XML is pretty new to me.  Another question is that with XML, am I getting the XML feed from the feed link itself (url.com/feed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) This is the basics and should get you pointed in the right direction. As far as getting the xml feed, API's vary on url's and requirements (and I cant be sure of the url without knowing which API you're using) depending on whether its a plugin or directly from your site.